# require_once fatal error (one more time)

Tags: php, fatal-error, require-once

I have created super simple script as same as before when everything worked properly. But somehow it stopped and now everytime I try to require a file it show me an error:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'E:\tools\EasyPHP\www/registry/registry.class.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in E:\tools\EasyPHP\www\index.php on line 18

My index file:

```
define("APP_PATH", dirname(__FILE__)."/");
require_once(APP_PATH.'registry/registry.class.php');
```

That is everything but i still can't load that page.

How should i set it up?  I'm using windows for local builds only.

Comment: file_exists(APP_PATH.'registry/registry.class.php') gives? If false then check APP_PATH.'registry/registry.class.php' against expected path of file

Comment: Probably dumb question but does `E:\tools\EasyPHP\www/registry/registry.class.php` exists?

Comment: yes it is but show me that it didn't even exist.

Comment: ok i have solved this. dreamweaver named file 'registry.class.php.php' and that was probbably my fault that i didn't noticed that. when I recreated files it became working properly. anyway using directory_separator is even better then single slash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
define( "APP_PATH", dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once( APP_PATH . 'registry' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'registry.class.php' );
```

The constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` evaluates to backslash on Windows systems and forward-slash on *nix systems. This way your code will work without modification on both Windows and Linux environments.

([See the PHP manual on this constant](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) and its friend `PATH_SEPARATOR`.)

If you're still having trouble, it's possible the file does not exist at that path, or that PHP does not have read permissions to the file.

Comment: Failed opening required 'E:\tools\EasyPHP\www\registry\registry.class.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')
while file actually exist and it has all save/read/write permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You see in result of your `dirname()` the string has `\` and in your other string you have `/`, i think you should only have `\`.

Comment: i did nothing to it, i set / separator only and backslash has been added to files by system. theres no even way to change it

Comment: In windows you use \ in php in the path to a file, when written in php. So you should write: `define("APP_PATH", dirname(__FILE__)."\");
require_once(APP_PATH.'registry\registry.class.php');`